# my command prompt is not opening on Chromebook on Code::Blocks

Tags: codeblocks

i am using Code Blocks on Chromebook and the command prompt is not opening when i run the program

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#Include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
printf("Hello world\n");

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Environment > General Settings.
Change the "Terminal to launch console programs"

Comment: what do i change it to